# How do I fill in missing data based on filled cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to fill in blanks in a column, the values of the blanks are based on the previous filled cell. I want to do this using google app script but i don't know how should I start approaching this problem.

before script

```
AAA
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
BBB
(blank)
(blank)
CCC
(blank)
DDD
EEE
(blank)
(blank)
```

After Script

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
CCC
CCC
DDD
EEE
EEE
EEE
```

Comment: How can we know about the 2 ``(blank)`` values below ``EEE``?

Comment: the (blank) below EEE will be EEE

Comment: the blank values are the closest filled value from above

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: What tanaike asked is that how will you know that there are only 2 blanks below 'EEE'? Or, if there are 1000 rows, and 'EEE' is in A10, should A11 to A1000 be filled with EEE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function fillBlanksWithLastValue() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]) {
      var lastValue= vA[i][0];
    }else{
      vA[i][0]=lastValue;
    }   
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

This might be a little better in case you have blank lines near the top.

```
function fillBlanksWithLastValue() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var lastValue='';
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]) {
      lastValue= vA[i][0];
    }else{
      if(lastValue) {
        vA[i][0]=lastValue;
      }
    }   
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```